# How to change view of the viewcontroller when change the orientation in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, orientation

I'm developing an iPhone application which supports 2 orientations. I have 2 UIView files for this view controller. I need to set corresponding UIView file to the view controller according to the device interface orientation. Can you guide me on how to change the orientation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use two views for both orientation? You can set autoresizemask properties of controls, if portrait and landscape both mode has similar control to be show at same place. Otherwise, you need to use two views in

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

or you can have notification of UIDevice

```
 UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification;

- (void)beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications;      // nestable
- (void)endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have set the `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` to return your supported orientations, you can use the following methods which can all be set in your UIViewController to check for orientation changes and then set your views:

```
// called just before the user interface starts to rotate - my advice would be to use this method to save a copy of the current orientation.
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

// called after the interface has finished rotating. Here, you can compare the old orientation with the new one - if you went from portrait to landscape, then update your views accordingly.
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

just give this delegate in your controller for both orientations.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```