# Annotation/drawing on image changes position on orientation change

Tags: ios, drawing

I am drawing on top of image using UIBezierPath

```
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x, endPoint.y - startPoint.y);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
```

[image]

When i change orientation the drawing moves

[image]

Is there a way to recalculate the points on orientation change ?

Comment: you helpful this two link [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621616/position-uiview-when-changing-orientation)      [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580052/how-to-change-view-of-the-viewcontroller-when-change-the-orientation-in-iphone?lq=1)

Comment: Hey, I got the same problem. Did you find solution?